# Short form of the Psychopathic Personality Inventory questionnaire

Tags: personality, reference-request, test, psychology

Recently I have been reviewing several articles related to psychopathy outside the forensic area and I have observed that a very popular questionnaire in a college setting is the [Psychopathic Personality Inventory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychopathic_Personality_Inventory)(PPI). So far I have not been able to find this questionnaire explicitly.

As far as I understand, the questionnaire was developed in this paper [Psychopathic Personality Traits and Somatization: Sex Differences and the Mediating Role of Negative Emotionality](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263105409_Psychopathic_Personality_Traits_and_Somatization_Sex_Differences_and_the_Mediating_Role_of_Negative_Emotionality)
by Scott O. Lilienfeld and Tanya H. Hess, 2001.

I was wondering if you could tell me where I can find the questionnaire?

I would appreciate it very much, thank you.

**Reference**:

- Levenson, M. R., Kiehl, K. A., & Fitzpatrick, C. M. (1995). Assessing psychopathic attributes in a noninstitutionalized population. Journal of personality and social psychology, 68(1), 151. https://doi.org/10.1037/0022-3514.68.1.151

Answer (score 1):

An open version of the PPI is available here: https://openpsychometrics.org/tests/LSRP.php

Comment: The linked PPI cites the source to be from Levenson, M.; Kiehl, K.; Fitzpatrick, C. (1995). "Assessing psychopathic attributes in a noninstitutionalized population". *Journal of Personality and Social Psychology, 68*, 151-158. Can you explain the discrepancy between that and the belief by the OP that the source is Lilenfield & Andrews (1996)?

Comment: Thanks Chris.  The original question cited a 2001 reference.  Prior to answering the question, I edited the question to include the 1996 reference.  But you are correct, the 1995 reference is better and I've now replaced the 1996 reference with the 1995 reference.  Good pick up.